# Poles not correct in Rigify add-on after skinning

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have a big problems with the Rigify addon. It seems that you need to have a slight bend for the knees and elbows (the natural bend) to get the poles for knees and elbows correct. If the poles are wrong and I try to fix change the poles afterwards I get weird twisting on legs. My solution was to reshape the basemesh a bit to get a slight correct bend and then the poles are correct. Is this a bug or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Closed; mentioned in manual:
"Limbs: Keep the legs as straight as possible in the front view (Rigify human works better in predictable cases). Give the knee and the elbow a slight bend angle (Rigify needs to know where your knee/elbow is pointing)."
A limitation just to be aware of